# What is the syntax to segregate date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to extract data from Toad based on year dates. 
The data is listed as mm/dd/yyyy and I want to segregate in terms on YYYY irrespetive of month and day-- separate file for 2012 , 2013 and so on.

Can anyone please help me on what to exactly mention in the "where" clause?

Comment: Something like `where extract(year from date) = 2012`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff
This statement is giving me errors. I'm not trying to extract the data in this code.. I just want to write a simple select statement with the date selection mentioned in the where clause.

Comment: The old style  `where to_char(myDateColumn, 'YYYY') = '2012'` should work.

Comment: @codeforme - when trying Gordon's comment, did you include 'date', or substitute the name of your date column?

Answer (score 2):

You can try following syntax:-

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE_COL) = 2012;
```

Comment: Why is the 'desired date' (year?) enclosed in single quotes? Extract gives you a number.

Comment: Now see my edit. I was in such a hurry. So error accepted. and btw thanx for correcting me.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I guess you misunderstood Alex Poole's point. `EXTRACT` returns a Number - no need to compare it to a string (in fact, it might hurt performance, e.g. if you have a function-based index on `EXTRACT(...)` ). Just get rid of the single quotes.

Comment: I clearly understand @AlexPoole point, but it is user-specific input. only thats y i have put quotes here. and yes i knonw that in integer comparing string wil cause an error.

Comment: I think that it will be understood better if you just put a year number in there instead of a 'YOUR DESIRED YEAR'

Answer (score 0):

This clause worked for me. Since I only wanted to select and segregated existing records from the DB.

Select * 
From table
where to_char(myDateColumn, 'YYYY') = '2012'